# SQL Server VDI Backup

Tags: c#, sql-server

My application should do backup of SQL Server 2008 R2 data. It works fine when app is on server. When I get app to client PC and connect to Server, server cannot find path...

So I decide to use VDI for Backup, find this page http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19449/Accessing-the-SQL-Server-Virtual-Device-Interface and after some changes, it works fine on local PC. But when I try to backup on server-client. I cant make VirtualDevice on server.

It looks like I need to set VDI server address to create VirtualDevice on server. After that I will be able to use stream to server.

Does anyone have solution? That c++ code is strange to me.

Or if there is another possibility how to make C# app backup database on remote server without using sharedFolder?

Thanks, Jakub

Comment: the Drive should be shared, once its shared use the UNC path and it will resolve the issue.

Comment: But that is exactly problem. Customers dont have to have shared folders. And if Thay have, they have mapped shared folders like disc. So server get path P:\Backup. But disc P is name for client PC not for Server PC. Any other idea?

Comment: thats why I said use UNC path, instead of using `P:\Backup.` use UNC path which would look something like `\\ClientPC\SharedFolder_backup`

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but customers of this app hasnt knowledge of Sharing folders etc. So I need to do backup from Application via normal click via file explorer. I cant clarify them how to share folders, write computer name to file path etc.

Comment: Well you will need to explain them, if they dont know how to share a drive you, dont let them do this. This backup stuff should be handled by people who has the appropriate knowledge, dont let any newbies near your databases, can get you in some serious trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

No matter where your drive is or what your drive is [Virtual/Physical] where you want to take a backup. As long as it is shared you will be able to take a backup there.

Say you have a ClientPC and You have shared a folder `P:\Backup`. Now when taking backup you will use the UNC path something like this....

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Test_DB] 
  TO  DISK = N'\\ClientPC\Backup\BackupFile.bak'
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is about VDI (virtual device interface) which is a way to stream the backups to his software - i.e. it won't use a network share nor a local file - it will stream to his code instead.

I do know you need to be in the sysadmin role to run VDI, however I'm not sure of more information about the exact requirements - I was curious about if something could be done via VDI and ran across this post in researching it.

Good luck..